# How to sort column in TableView JavaFx?

Tags: sorting, tableview, javafx-8

I'm trying to sort the columns by clicking the column head. The problem is that he does not sort the column defined as Integer.
I wrote comparator for Integer but I think that this is not the way to sort column.

The code below belongs the client:

```
public class Client4 extends Application
{ // IO streams
private DataOutputStream toServer = null;
private DataInputStream fromServer = null;
private TableView<Student> tableView = new TableView<Student>();
private ObservableList<Student> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private ComboBox<String> cboStudent = new ComboBox<>();
private ComboBox<String> cboLecturer = new ComboBox<>();
private ArrayList<TableColumn> tableCol = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();
private Callback<TableColumn<Student, String>, TableCell<Student, String>> cellFactory
= (TableColumn<Student, String> p) -> new EditingCell();
@Override // Override the start method in the Application class
public void start(Stage primaryStage)  throws Exception
{ // Panel p to hold the label and text field
    Button btAddRow = new Button("Add Student");
    Button btDeleteRow = new Button("Delete Student");
    Button btEdit = new Button("Edit");
    Button btAddColumn = new Button("Add Column");
    Button btDeleteColumn = new Button("Delete Column");
    tableView.setItems(data);
    //tableView.setEditable(true);
    //      Callback<TableColumn<Student, String>, TableCell<Student, String>> cellFactory
    //            = (TableColumn<Student, String> p) -> new EditingCell();

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5)); 
    HBox hBox = new HBox(20);

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btAddRow, btDeleteRow, 
            btEdit, btAddColumn, btDeleteColumn);
    pane.setTop(hBox);
    try {

        //  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8000);
        // Create an input stream to receive data from the server
        fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        // Create an output stream to send data to the server
        toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ArrayList<String> lables = new ArrayList<String>();
        int numberRecords=0;
        numberRecords = fromServer.readInt();
        System.out.println(numberRecords);
        while (numberRecords>0)
        {   String record =fromServer.readUTF();
        lables.add(record);
        cboStudent.getItems().add(record);
        numberRecords--;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<lables.size();i++)
        {
            String lable = lables.get(i);
            TableColumn<Student, String> string = new TableColumn<Student, String>(lable);
            string.setMinWidth(100);
            if (lable.equals("firstName") || lable.equals("lastName") || lable.equals("city") || lable.equals("street") || lable.equals("dept") )
            {               
                string.setCellValueFactory(
                        new PropertyValueFactory<Student, String>(lable));
                defineCell(string);

                //                  ObservableList<String> cbValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");
                //                  string.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), cbValues));
                tableView.getColumns().add(string);
                tableCol.add(string);
            }
            else if(lable.equals("birthDate"))
            {
                TableColumn<Student, Date> date = new TableColumn<Student, Date>(lable);
                date.setCellValueFactory(
                        new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Date>(lable));
                //defineCell(date);
                tableView.getColumns().add(date);
                tableCol.add(date);
            }
            else if(lable.equals("picture"))
            {
                TableColumn<Student, ImageView> pic = new TableColumn<Student, ImageView>(lable);
                pic.setCellValueFactory(
                        new PropertyValueFactory<Student, ImageView>(lable));
                tableView.getColumns().add(pic);
                tableCol.add(pic);
            }
            else 
            {
                TableColumn<Student, Integer> integer = new TableColumn<Student, Integer>(lable);
                integer.setCellValueFactory(
                        new PropertyValueFactory<Student, Integer>(lable));
                integer.setSortable(true);
                integer.setComparator(new Comparator<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                        if(o1<o2) return 1;
                        if(o1>o2)return -1;
                        return 0;
                    }
                });

                tableView.getColumns().add(integer);
                tableCol.add(integer);
            }


        }
        numberRecords=0;
        numberRecords=fromServer.readInt();
        while(numberRecords>0)
        {   Student student = new Student();
        student.setId(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setFirstName(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setLastName(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setCity(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setStreet(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setHouseNumber(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setZipCode(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setBirthDate(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setPicture(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setStartYear(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setDept(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setCredits(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setAverage(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setNumFailed(fromServer.readUTF());
        student.setPlace(fromServer.readUTF());
        System.out.println(student);
        data.add(student);
        numberRecords--;
        }
        tableView.setItems(data);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {

    }

    btEdit.setOnAction(e -> {
        editTable(btEdit.toString());

    });


    pane.setBottom(tableView);
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 890, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("ShowCombination"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage  
    primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
}

private void defineCell(TableColumn<Student, String> string) {
    string.setCellFactory(cellFactory);        
    string.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Student, String> t) -> {
                ((Student) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setFirstName(t.getNewValue());
            });

    ObservableList<String> cbValues = FXCollections.observableArrayList("1", "2", "3");
    string.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new DefaultStringConverter(), cbValues));        

}

private void editTable(String string) {
    tableView.setEditable(true);
    Student student=(Student)tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{ launch(args);
}
class EditingCell extends TableCell<Student, String> {

    private TextField textField;

    public EditingCell() {
    }

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            super.startEdit();
            createTextField();
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText((String) getItem());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (isEditing()) {
                if (textField != null) {
                    textField.setText(getString());
                }
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                setText(getString());
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
                (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
                        Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
                            if (!arg2) {
                                commitEdit(textField.getText());
                            }
                        });
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your `ObservableList` holding the `TableView` data in a [`SortedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html):

```
SortedList<Student> sortedItems = new SortedList<>(data);
tableView.setItems(sortedItems);
```

Next you need to link both together:

```
sortedItems.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());
```

And as a friendly side note: Please consider posting a smaller code example showing only what is necessary to demonstrate your problem ;-)

Comment: I think he just wants the default behavior of clicking on the table header.  There shouldn't be any reason to use a sorted list.  We don't even know if Student implements comparator.

Comment: @brian To my knowledge sorting only works if you make explicit use of the `SortedList`?

Comment: No, clicking on the header will sort the table in the columns natural sort order.

Comment: I want to sort each column by setting I got not by Default, for example, integers I want to sort by third root

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "third root" (unless you mean "cube root", but that would be redundant; the order would be exactly the same as the natural ("default") order). But all you should need to do is set the comparator. As commented in your question, please create (from scratch if necessary) a complete, simple example we can run that demonstrates what goes wrong.

Comment: @brian Note that a `SortedList<E>` doesn't require that `E` implement `Comparable`. The `SortedList` uses a `Comparator<E>` to determine its sort order. A `null` comparator just means "don't sort". The difference between this solution and just using the default behavior is that adding new items to the underlying list will insert them into the table in the correct order; though that is different (I think) to what the OP is asking.

Comment: @James_D another difference is that "unsorting" works only with sortedList

Answer (score 0):

As James_D says, cube root will sort in the same order, but here's a little example you can use to show what you're trying to do

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableSort extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView tv = new TableView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                IntStream.of(1,-2,3,-4,-5,6)
                        .map(n->{return (int)Math.pow(n, 3);})
                        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())));

        TableColumn<Integer, Integer> numCol = new TableColumn("num");
        numCol.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue());
        });

        TableColumn<Integer, Integer> cbrtCol = new TableColumn("cube root");
        cbrtCol.setCellValueFactory((param) -> {
            return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>((int)Math.cbrt(param.getValue()));
        });

        numCol.setComparator((Integer o1, Integer o2) -> {
            return Double.compare(Math.cbrt(o1), Math.cbrt(o2));
        });

        tv.getColumns().addAll(numCol, cbrtCol);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tv);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It is close to what I mean, but it does not work when:
'TableColumn<Student, Integer> integer = new TableColumn<Student,Integer>(lable);
integer.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Student,Integer>(lable));
     //integer.setSortable(true);
      
     integer.setComparator((Integer o1, Integer o2) -> {
               return Integer.compare((o1), (o2));
           });'

Comment: Please edit the question to include a minimal, executable example that shows this "not working". What do you mean by "does not work"? (Doesn't compile? Throws exceptions? Doesn't sort correctly?)